# Derivatives of characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, taylor-expansion, characteristic-functions

Let $\phi$ be the characteristic function for random variable $X$.
I know that if $E [|X|] < \infty$, then dominated convergence implies existence of the first derivative, and in particular, $\phi'(0) = i E[X]$. More generally if $E[|X|^k]<\infty$, then $\phi^{(k)}(0) = i^k E[X^k]$.

However, how can I argue the converse? Specifically, if I know $\phi$ is infinitely differentiable at $0$ and has a Taylor series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!} \phi^{(k)}(0)$ that converges everywhere, how can I conclude that $\phi^{(k)}(0) = i^k E[X^k]$ and further that $E[|X|^k]<\infty$? I am not sure how to make the leap from existence of the derivative to claiming that it must be what we think it should be ($i^k E[X^k]$)...

Comment: Look at Problem 8.6 in https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiw9MDMgonJAhUK5GMKHV4IC0A&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ma.utexas.edu%2Fusers%2Fgordanz%2Fnotes%2Fcharacteristic.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFKW-FxQYKkqFCErGY6Q0raIt3ibg&sig2=TQ86FpdolCQI3wVUIg8S5Q.

Comment: @copper.hat Ah thank you, being in $L^k$ was not true after all...

Comment: It is a good question. Too many folks let this sort of thing slide.

Comment: @copper.hat Just to clarify, in the context of my question I have all derivatives, so the issue in your link is not a problem here, correct? Thank you for bringing it to my attention though!

Comment: Correct, since all even orders exist (and $E|X|^{n+1} < \infty$ implies  $E|X|^{n} < \infty$) then all moments exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: First show that if $\phi$ has even order derivative then all moments exist upto that order of derivative. Here you have infinitely differentiable $\phi$ so obviously all even order derivatives exist and hence all moments exist.

By the way, the first part is a standard inclusion in probability textbooks.

Comment: This is what I was missing, thank you!